# Sending Object Directly with socket

Tags: c#, sockets

i am beginner developer with c#
I trying to develop client server capture winform application 
in this app image captured from desktop of client and then put in to temporary file and then send it to server with socket .(I Said I'm Beginner !)...

i have a question . may i put captured image to an object and sending this object directly with socket to server ?

i know data must be put into byte[] array for transferring but i can't write code for this idea . may you help me in this problem ?

thanks a lot .

Comment: You can't send an object directly. It will need to be transferred into a flat format - a process known in .NET as serialization. Google that and you'll find many examples.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can send this image from client to server by writing this to the networkstream as byte[].

Here is an example on how to send this binary "message" (read: image) from client to server using sockets.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12286/Simple-Client-server-Interactions-using-C

Comment: wow , its very complicated , do you have any idea for use this class?

Comment: I would have thought that was one of the most easiest to follow client server example. What is your deadline? Maybe I can help you out with something else.